# Screenshot from a user's mouse input with Python?

Tags: python, screenshot

So i want to implement a global and partial screenshot tool (like snipping tool in Windows) with python. I want user to input the area that he wants to screenshot with mouse. I can use pyscreenshot module but how can i manipulate the input on :

```
im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,510,510)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
```

in the example given?

p.s. https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot module's repository

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
cursor = X.NONE
self.window.grab_pointer(1,X.PointerMotionMask|X.ButtonReleaseMask|X.ButtonPressMask,X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, X.NONE, cursor, X.CurrentTime)
```

See a complete example [here](https://gist.github.com/initbrain/6628609)

Comment: this needs PyQt4 install which i want to avoid cause it seems i cannot install it on my macbook. Also this python-xlib docs are terrible. I just need to promt the user for a rectangle and then save this coords i guess